# How to change properties values in Firebug inspector with the mouse wheel?

Tags: firebug

I found that you can scroll the values of the inspected element using the Chrome inspector.
Now I'd like to do the same with Firebug inspector.

Example (in Chrome):
You select a div and it has the property: **padding: 10px;** You double click over **10px** and then you can use the mouse wheel to increase / decrease its value.

Is there any way to do this with Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you've found something where Firebug works differently to Chrome Devtools.

You're just going to have to accept that they work differently in this respect. You can use the up/down arrow keys to change the values in Firebug, but not the scroll wheel. That's just the way it works.

Personally, I prefer the scrollwheel to work the way it does in Firebug -- ie scrolling the list of styles. But that's just my personal preference. But either way, you're not going to be able to change Firebug's behaviour in this respect without digging into the codebase and modifying it yourself.

Comment: I didn't know I can use the arrow keys in Firebug to change values. This is just fine for me. Thanks